# build a qt 4.6 from a qt 4.8

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, qt4.8, qt4.6

I have a project in `qt-creator`.
that computer have `Qt: 4.8.2`

one of the computers i want to run the application on have `Qt: 4.6.2`

I can see that qt-creator have an option under the project for QtVersions,
but i only got one option there "`Qt 4.8.1 (System)`"

Id like to have `Qt 4.6.x` as an option there too, how do i add/install that?

Target computer:

```
kde4-config --version
Qt: 4.6.2
KDE Development Platform: 4.4.2 (KDE 4.4.2)
kde4-config: 1.0

uname -a
Linux fw-01 2.6.32-24-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 19 01:12:52 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Build computer:

```
kde4-config --version
Qt: 4.8.2
KDE Development Platform: 4.8.5 (4.8.5)
kde4-config: 1.0

uname -a
Linux rito 3.3.8-gentoo #3 SMP Thu Sep 13 10:11:22 CEST 2012 i686 AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 245 Processor AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Did you install the Qt SDK, or are you are just using what your distro provided?

Comment: i installed gentoos "dev-util/qt-creator-2.5.0" that compiles it from http://get.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator/qt-creator-2.5.0-src.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

As the SDK doesn't support the old versions anymore, you will have to compile the libraries from source.  [The archive FTP site](ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/) has the version you want.

Though I should point out that as long as you are linking dynamically and your code base doesn't use features post-v4.6.2 - then it will work as expected.  If you are, then compiling using v4.6.2 headers isn't going to change anything - you will still have to upgrade the other computer or remove the newer Qt features from your application.

Comment: Installed QT SDK in my users homefolder, and now i have 2 options insted of 1, the old "Qt 4.8.1 (System)" and "Desktop Qt 4.8.1 for GCC (Qt SDK)", still no 4.6

Comment: And did you specify which versions of Qt you needed during the installation?  You should have been presented with a tree view with all the advanced installation options.

Comment: tried both "Qt SDK 1.2.1" and "Qt SDK 1.1.2", under "Develement Tools->Desktop Qt", there is an 4.7.3 avible, is that where you expected med to find a 4.6?

Comment: You're right, they must have changed to repos to avoid clashing with Digia's commercial version.  I'll update my question to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround,

- installing kubuntu 10.04 in a vitrualbox
- copy the project to the virtualbox
- compile it using qt-creator inside virtualbox

The binary made in the virtualbox works fine in both 4.6 and 4.8 envirement

Answer (score -1):

In Qt Creator, try tools -> options -> Qt Versions (or Build/run, then qt versions, or some other abomination depending on what qt creator version you have).

Should see a list of Qt versions it knows about.  Click add to reference your 4.6 qmake manually.  That should get creator to pick it up.

Comment: -1 But that would mean Puggan Se would have to build his application on the target machine instead of his build machine.

Comment: Oh I thought that was the question.  If not, when you deploy, you have to bring the right version of the libraries with you.